# HttpRequestException Always Implies Status Code of 500

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this bit of code in my controller's action method:

```
throw new HttpRequestException("Here's the exception.",
    new Exception("I am the inner exception"),
    System.Net.HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed);
```

Note that the `MethodNotAllowed` is a 405 code. In Postman, however, this always comes across as a 500 status. This happens no matter what status code I use, something is always changing it to 500. Why would this be?

Comment: Because there is no middleware in your pipeline that generally handles exceptions. In that case the default middleware jumps in and returns a 500 error response. So if you like your own handling of exceptions and get the status code from the exception itself, you have to implement your own [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) that handles that.

Comment: @Oliver, now why would the "default middleware" change the HTTP status code? I do not want my own, "handling of exceptions". 

The problem is that the client is seeing a 500 instead of a 405.

Comment: Nope. You have to implement your own (but that's quite easy).